# In Principles of Mathematical Analysis, why does Rudin define derivatives in terms of closed intervals?

Tags: analysis

This is how Rudin defines the derivative of a function.

[image]

Why does he do it in terms of closed intervals? My impression is that for a derivative to exist at a point, the function must be defined in some open neighborhood of the point. However, Rudin seems to imply that this isn't the case; he seems to imply the the derivative at $a$ (in his notation) exists.

Comment: Apparently he finds it convenient to have the derivative defined at the endpoints as well (as what are usually called the right and left one-sided derivatives there).

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see. However, this may create problems. Consider the function ReLU in machine learning. ReLU(x) := max(0, x). According to Rudin, since the function is defined on [0, 1], then the derivative at 0 is 1...

Comment: @extremeaxe5 So the function on $[0,1]$ satisfying $x\mapsto x$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$. What is problematic about that?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No, I'm saying that Rudin seems to imply that given any real valued function mapping from some subset of ℝ, we can find the derivative at a point by first choosing a closed interval containing it, and then using Rudin's method. However, as the above function shows, this allows for a derivative to be defined as two different values. If you picked [-1, 0] as your interval, you would have gotten the derivative as 0.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 I disagree; Rudin does not "seem to imply" anything of the sort.

Comment: I agree that Rudin's phrasing seems a bit confusing, because what does it mean for a function $f$ to be "defined on an interval $[a,b]$"?  Does it mean that $[a,b]$ is a subset of the domain of $f$, or that $[a,b]$ is the domain of $f$? I think Rudin is assuming that $[a,b]$ is actually the *domain* of the function. But that seems overly restrictive, because we will want to take derivatives of other functions with more complicated domains.

Comment: To specify a function, you must specify its domain. It just so happens that in the case of your ReLU function, the formula is the same, but since the domains are different, it makes sense that the “derivative” as Rudin defines it be different at the same point. (After all, if you opted for the domain $[-1,1]$, the function would not have been differentiable to start with.)

Comment: @littleO These are exactly my thoughts. I was wondering whether Rudin meant that, but I thought it would be overly restrictive. That's why I thought it meant for it to be a subset of the domain.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So then what is Rudin saying? Is he saying that you can only take derivatives of functions whose domain is a closed interval? This seems a bit restrictive...

Comment: @extremeaxe5 Rudin is defining the derivative of a function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Right, and then he goes on to take the derivative of f(x) = x. I believe the domain of this function is not a closed interval.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 The function $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$ are different functions. There is no such thing as "the" domain for a particular rule. (Nor do all functions fall into the "domain and rule" paradigm. In the usual definition, a function is a set of ordered pairs that "pass the vertical line test" and its domain is the set of all $x$-values of the pairs.)

Comment: Since you are using Rudin's book, have you checked how he defines a function to begin with? @extremeaxe5

Comment: When Rudin takes the derivative of the function $f(x) =x$, I think he means the function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, where $[a,b]$ is a closed interval. I notice that Rudin defines the derivative of a function defined on an open interval, in a comment after the definition for the case where $f$ is defined on a closed interval. It seems like it would have been nice for Rudin to provide a more general definition that would work for functions with more complicated domains, but perhaps Rudin thought this was unnecessary (and easy to do if needed later).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm not sure exactly what you are saying. Are you saying that functions do not need to fix a domain beforehand, and the domain is determined ad hoc?

Comment: @extremeaxe5 No I was saying that if you're defining a function using a "domain + rule" sort of prescription, you need to specify the domain, and in general there are many possible choices. So when you said "the domain of $f(x) = x$  is not a closed interval" that doesn't make any sense, since there are tons of possible domains on which you could define a function via the rule $f(x)=x$ (in fact, any set of any kind could serve as a domain, including any closed interval).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen well, the domain of $f(x) = x$ is assumed to be $\mathbb{R}$. At least, I believe this is the case if the domain isn't specified. Rudin never specified his domain, so I assumed he was talking about the entire real line.